# ADODB CommandTimeout executing stored procedure in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I have a problem in a very old project. There is a timeout exception during a long database process.

Here is initial code

```
Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCmd.ActiveConnection = Common_CnxStr
objCmd.CommandText = "Db.SP_Name"
objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
/*some query parameters are added here*/  
objCmd.Execute
```

This runs for 90 seconds then fails with timeout exception. How can I increase the timeout to, for example, 5 minutes.

I tried to extend the timeout by adding to my code the line objCmd.CommandTimeout

```
Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCmd.CommandTimeout = 300 
objCmd.ActiveConnection = Common_CnxStr
objCmd.CommandText = "Db.SP_Name"
objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
/*some query parameters are added here*/  
objCmd.Execute
```

But this does not work and I still have an exception after 90 seconds. I even tried to do like this

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 300
Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCmd.CommandTimeout = 300 
objCmd.ActiveConnection = Common_CnxStr
objCmd.ActiveConnection.CommandTimeout = 300
objCmd.CommandText = "Db.SP_Name"
objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
/*some query parameters are added here*/  
objCmd.Execute
```

But this did not change anything. Please help.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? It could be due to Server.ScriptTimeout instead of the ADODB timeout! "The Internet Information Services (IIS) default setting for the ASP script timeout is 90 seconds. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add this at the beginning of your ASP code:

```
<%
  Server.ScriptTimeout = 300 ' 5 minutes!
%>
```

Anyway, if it is a performance issue, you should get the DBA to check the DB instead

See also:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb632464.aspx